# Are direct function calls executed faster than callback function calls?

Tags: c, function, callback

I have two independent process: one using callback function calls and another using normal function calls. Which process will be executed faster?

Comment: What do you mean with "call back functionality implemented"?

Comment: call back function is nothing but, using the function pointers

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 2):

As Srinuvenu said, calling a callback function is like calling a function pointer.
When you call a function pointer, what happens is that the address of the function in the pointer is retrieved. You have the following scenarios:

**Direct function call:**
*Execute code at specified address.*

**Callback function call:**
*Get the address of the function* → *Execute code at specified address.*

As you can see, calling a callback function adds an additional step: Retrieving the address of the function. In conclusion, using callbacks is slower than direct function calls, but because the address-retrieving step is very fast (as Mabus said bellow), **call's speeds should be very similar**.

Comment: But that step is very fast. In fact, most OO programing languages uses callbacks all the time to achieve polymorphism.